# Upload multiple files from two fileupload controls in asp.net 4.0 withou using postedfiles property of file upload control

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have two file upload controls
 

And this is the code to save multiple files
c#
 string filepath = Server.MapPath("~//Files/Documents/test/");
        HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;

```
    //Span1.Text = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];

        try
        {
            if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                Response.Write(userPostedFile.FileName);

                userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath  + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName));                  
                //Span1.Text += "Location where saved: " +   filepath + "\\" +   Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName) + "<p>";
            }
        }

        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            //Span1.Text += "Error: <br>" + Ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This are two file upload controls: <asp:FileUpload ID="fup1" runat="server" Enabled="False" AllowMultiple="true"/> &  <asp:FileUpload ID="fup2" runat="server" Enabled="False" AllowMultiple="true"/>&nbsp;</td>

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: but since i have used request.files it saves all the files irrespective of which fileupload control i use

Comment: i want save files seperately from each fileupload control